# Micronaut Data - Pageable or Flowable.skip().limit()?

Tags: rx-java2, micronaut, micronaut-data

I was wondering if someone could explain the differences and pros and cons of each approach. Ie. the underlying queries to DBs, performance, etc

1. RxJava approach

```java
RxJavaCrudRepository.findAll().skip(offset).limit(max)
```

2. Pageable approach

```java
CrudRepository.findAll(Pageable.from(offset, max))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some digging around and debugging the resulting SQL, I have come to the conclusion that:
Approach 1 doesnt do any under-the-hood magic and uses a SELECT without LIMIT, fetching all rows from DB and then applying the skip/offset. This means it definitely should not be used and approach 2 is the way to go.